# Maven install issue with Java 1.8 version

Tags: java, maven

I have written code which can compile on Java 1.8 (try block). It is compiled and running for me when I run it directly. While I am trying to build it using Maven in my local, I am facing an issue which is saying to use -source 7 or later. I tried all possible ways to use java 8 and all places I have specified 8 only but Maven is trying to compile using java 1.6 it seems.

Can any one you please help me where can I correct it to pick my maven to use java 1.8.

Thanks,
Venkat

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Could be classpath issues or the like.

Answer (score 3):

Following should work too:

```
<properties>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
</properties>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify that using the `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0<</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Just remember to use the newest version of the plugin.

Comment: @JigarJoshi the OP said that he is able to run that so it suggests that `JAVA_HOME` is set properly

Comment: You should add maven.compiler.target and source properties with this plugin